# How to deal with " RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, stack-overflow

I'm developping an `express` API. It runs well on my computer but on my server I meet the following exception:

> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

The code consist in reading a file of ~400000 lines. Then it loops on each line and have a recursive call of depth 15 at most on it.
I read about `setImmediate` and `process.nextTick` but I'm not sure on how or where to use them.

Any idea of what's happening and how to fix it?

I already tried to change stack size (to the size of my file) but it it doesn't solve this problem. I suppose it's more a structural problem.

**Sample code**

```
const bigProcess = () => {
    const processLine = (line) => {
        let l = line && line.charAt(0);
        if (l) {
            if (line.length > 1) {
                processLine(line.substring(1));
            } else {
                console.log('line processed.');
            }
        }
    };

    var data = fs.readFileSync("myfile.txt", "utf-8");
    var lines = data.toString().split("\r\n");
    for (var line of lines) {
        processLine(line);
    }
};
```

Here is my full output:

> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
>       at String.charAt ()
>       at processLine (/home/sinsedrix/myapi/bigprocess.js:7:30)
>       at processLine (/home/sinsedrix/myapi/bigprocess.js:14:17)
>       at processLine (/home/sinsedrix/myapi/bigprocess.js:14:17)
>       at processLine (/home/sinsedrix/myapi/bigprocess.js:14:17)
>       at processLine (/home/sinsedrix/myapi/bigprocess.js:14:17)
>       at processLine (/home/sinsedrix/myapi/bigprocess.js:14:17)
>       at processLine (/home/sinsedrix/myapi/bigprocess.js:14:17)
>       at processLine (/home/sinsedrix/myapi/bigprocess.js:14:17)
>       at processLine (/home/sinsedrix/myapi/bigprocess.js:14:17)
>       at processLine (/home/sinsedrix/myapi/bigprocess.js:14:17)
>       at processLine (/home/sinsedrix/myapi/bigprocess.js:14:17)
>       at processLine (/home/sinsedrix/myapi/bigprocess.js:14:17)
>       at processLine (/home/sinsedrix/myapi/bigprocess.js:14:17)
>       at processLine (/home/sinsedrix/myapi/bigprocess.js:14:17)
>       at processLine (/home/sinsedrix/myapi/bigprocess.js:14:17)
>       at processLine (/home/sinsedrix/myapi/bigprocess.js:14:17)
>       at processLine (/home/sinsedrix/myapi/bigprocess.js:14:17)
>       at processLine (/home/sinsedrix/myapi/bigprocess.js:14:17)
>       at processLine (/home/sinsedrix/myapi/bigprocess.js:14:17)
>       at processLine (/home/sinsedrix/myapi/bigprocess.js:14:17)
>       at processLine (/home/sinsedrix/myapi/bigprocess.js:14:17)

Comment: Whooooaaa! a real stack overflow here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: can you show an example input and output?

Comment: How long are your lines? If your lines pass the stack size of around 10000 then you'll get a stack overflow.

Comment: Keep in mind that the stack is more than just the file you read in, it is also the memory needed to run your code and the VM itself. So I would increase it to more than just the file size to rule out memory (leak) issues. You're breaking down the file into very small pieces and each piece takes some more memory overhead than just the file data itself.

Comment: You have over simplified the problem presented here. currently `processLine` can be replaced with `if (line) console.log("line processed")`. what does your real function do?

Comment: @Aplet123 my lines are 15 length max (that's recursion shouldn't go more than 15 depth)

Comment: @Thankyou I'm filling a js object like a tree.

Comment: You might want to post your full code as it seems nothing is wrong here. Also make sure you don't have any stray lines that happen to be greater than 15 characters, and try splitting on `\n` instead.

Comment: @Aplet123 you had the good intuition about `\n`. When I pushed my files on github, it replaced line endings from `\r\n` to `\n` so my files where like an unique line of 4Mb :/

Comment: To avoid end of line bugs, I'm going to use `readline` https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_example_read_file_stream_line_by_line